# Does the draggable property of the google maps marker (v3) influence the zIndex of the marker?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have a map, a marker with zIndex = 6, and when i click on it an infobox appears (zIndex: 5 and pane: "overlayImage"). So the marker and the tooltip are in the same pane so it depends of the zIndex which is on top and which is under. The problem that i have is that if the marker has (draggable: true) the zIndex compare works. (marker is on top because 6>5), but if i delete the draggable property, the marker will be under the infobox even if the zindex is higher than the infobox zIndex.

Can somebody explain me why this happens? Code:

```
function initialize() {

    var secheltLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307);

    var myMapOptions = {
         zoom: 15
        ,center: secheltLoc
        ,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var theMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myMapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: theMap,
        draggable: true,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(49.47216, -123.76307),
        zIndex: 6
    });

    var boxText = document.createElement("div");
    boxText.style.cssText = "zindex: 3;border: 1px solid black; margin-top: 8px; background: yellow; padding: 5px;";
    boxText.innerHTML = "City Hall, Sechelt<br>British Columbia<br>Canada";

    var myOptions = {
         content: boxText
        ,disableAutoPan: false
        ,maxWidth: 0
        ,pixelOffset: new google.maps.Size(-10, -20)
        ,zIndex: 5
        ,boxStyle: {
          background: "url('tipbox.gif') no-repeat"
          ,opacity: 0.75
          ,width: "280px"
         }
        ,closeBoxMargin: "10px 2px 2px 2px"
        ,closeBoxURL: "http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/close.gif"
        ,infoBoxClearance: new google.maps.Size(1, 1)
        ,isHidden: false
        ,pane: "overlayImage"
        ,enableEventPropagation: false
    };

    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function (e) {
        ib.open(theMap, this);        
    });
}
```

Comment: I posted the example here http://jsfiddle.net/paulalexandru21/cAVCN/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set the marker to draggable, it is not optimized (not rendered in canvas).

If you set the optimized to false, it will have the same effect (without setting the marker to draggable).

Comment: I dont want to set the marker to draggable, but this is the only solution i found in order the zindex to work. I want to delete this property, but i need to know what changes i have to make in order to work. (the marker remain on top of the infobox, using the zIndex)

Comment: That wasn't clear from your question (that you didn't want the marker draggable). See the updated answer.